# How to access list of objects inside of model (parent object) using Razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I would like to ask for help about asp.net core using Razor pages and how to access list inside of model to display them on page (cshtml).
Hopefully picture will give a better explanation what I have and what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks for any help

This *VnetObject* class

```
public class VnetObject
    {
        public string VnetName { get; set; }
        public string VnetRange { get; set; }
        public string VnetDnsServers { get; set; }
        public List<SubnetObject> SubnetObjects { get; set; }
    }
```

This is *SubnetObject* class

```
public class SubnetObject
    {
        public string SubnetName { get; set; }
        public string SubnetRange { get; set; }
        public string SubnetNsg { get; set; }
    }
```

This is code page *Vnet.cshtml*

```
    @if (Model.VnetObjects != null)
{
    @foreach (var vnetItem in Model.VnetObjects)
    {
        <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VnetObjects[0].VnetName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VnetObjects[0].VnetRange)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VnetObjects[0].VnetDnsServers)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => vnetItem.VnetName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => vnetItem.VnetRange)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => vnetItem.VnetDnsServers)
                </td>
                <td>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        @foreach (var subnetItem in ) // What to write here to access SubnetObject
        {
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor() // What to write here to access SubnetObject
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor()
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor()
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor()  // What to write here to access SubnetObject
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor()
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor()
                </td>
                <td>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        }
    }
}
```

How to access any property of *VnetObject* even if they are nested?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF3QV.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; C) are difficult to read clearly by visual impaired user and many more reasons. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. For me it did not work using *foreach* loop but using *for* loop.
Here is code I have used.

```
@if (Model.VnetObjects != null)
{
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.VnetObjects.Count; i++)
   {
       <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VnetObjects[0].VnetName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VnetObjects[0].VnetRange)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VnetObjects[0].VnetDnsServers)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VnetObjects[i].VnetName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VnetObjects[i].VnetRange)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VnetObjects[i].VnetDnsServers)
                </td>
                <td>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        @for (var j = 0; j < Model.VnetObjects[i].SubnetObjects.Count; j++)
        {
            <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VnetObjects[0].SubnetObjects[0].SubnetName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VnetObjects[0].SubnetObjects[0].SubnetRange)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VnetObjects[0].SubnetObjects[0].SubnetNsg)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VnetObjects[i].SubnetObjects[j].SubnetName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VnetObjects[i].SubnetObjects[j].SubnetRange)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VnetObjects[i].SubnetObjects[j].SubnetNsg)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        }
   }
}
```

Formatting is not proper and displaying data in table needs to be fixed but how to display data is solved.